# Parameterize fixture factory in Pytest

Tags: python, parameters, pytest, fixtures

I have a dummy name factory fixture:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def dummy_name():
    def func(name="Dummy Name"):
        yield name
        num = 2
        while True:
            yield f"{name}_{num}"
            num += 1

    return func
```

And I have a fixture which utilizes this:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def dummy_document_file_name(dummy_name, extension):
    if extension:
        return dummy_name(name="test_file" + f".{extension}")
    return dummy_name(name="test_file.dummy_extension")
```

However `extension` supposed to be not another fixture but a parameter provided by the user of this fixture.

So I'd like to achieve this:

```py
dummy_file = next(dummy_document_file_name(extension="txt")) # test_file.txt
dummy_file2 = next(dummy_document_file_name(extension="txt")) # test_file2.txt
```

Naturally it looks for another fixture:

```sh
  @pytest.fixture
  def dummy_document_file_name(dummy_name, extension):
E       fixture 'extension' not found
>       available fixtures: ...
```

Is there a way to inject non-fixture parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use params in the fixture decorator to set default values, `request` to get the parameters passed to the fixture, and the `pytest.mark.parameterize` decorator to set the parameters on the test level. In `pytest.mark.parameterize` you have to define the name of the fixture you want to parameterize, pass the parameters as an iterable, and, most importantly, set the indirect flag to True. In code, that reads like

```py
@pytest.fixture(params=[None])
def dummy_document_file_name(dummy_name, request):
    if extension := request.param:
        return dummy_name(name="test_file" + f".{extension}")
    return dummy_name(name="test_file.dummy_extension")


@pytest.mark.parametrize('dummy_document_file_name', ("csv","pdf",None), indirect=True)
def test_this(dummy_document_file_name):
    print(dummy_document_file_name)
    assert True
```